# Is my employer entitled to the compensation from a delayed train that they paid for?

Tags: uk, trains, business-travel, compensation

I recently started a job in the UK that has frequent train journeys. My employer pays expenses when travelling to offices that aren't my home office. In the rail policy it states

> any compensation given directly to staff is not for personal use as it is compensation for shortfalls in delivery of service paid for not by the employee

I was under the impression that the compensation would go to the employee because they are the ones who suffer the effects of a delayed train. I suspect the train companies are against such policies as they only allow compensation to be claimed by the individual taking the journey, but does my employer violate some agreement or contract made with the booking service by having such a policy?

Comment: The employee endures the delay but the employer loses out on their time - presumably you get paid whether you’re sitting in an office or delayed on a train, for example? My own employer had a similar policy for journeys they paid for.

Comment: Hi, welcome to travel.SE. If I read your question right, the rail policy is that of your company's, but not the railway operator's. As such, I'd say the policy varies from company to company, and there is not much we could really answer here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a question about law and policy not travel.

Comment: Imagine that your employer buys a chair for your office, the chair breaks and the payment for the chair is refunded. Following your argumentation, you should as an employee be entitled to the refund because you suffer the effect of the broken chair. Do you find that reasonable?

Comment: On the other hand (@Tor-EinarJarnbjo) rail delays can very often mean that the employee loses a lot of time that should be off the clock.

Comment: This would be a better question for [Workplace.SE].

Comment: @HenningMakholm Workplace.SE will close it as it is about company policy, which is company-specific.

Comment: @B.Liu on the other hand, a question about whether UK law allows a policy such as this would be on topic at [Law.SE].

Comment: @B.Liu well it’s not a travel question regardless.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Not disagreeing with you, and what phoog said.

Comment: @ChrisH it's not entirely clear, but there's definitely an argument to be made that travel to an office other than the home office should in fact be on the clock.  If it is, the employer has a much stronger case with respect to the delayed train compensation.

Comment: @phoog but if you're not paid overtime and it's not long enough to get time off in lieu (a common case for a late finish in the UK, planned or otherwise), then what?

Comment: In almost all of the cases, this would be an automated refund to the payment method used to buy the ticket. So it will certainly go to the employer. I do not think there is a policy either with any employer or the train to hand out the refund to you personally.

Comment: @BhushanKale That's just not true. It's usually not automatic, passengers have to claim for it, and when they do, they can usually specify how they want it paid to them. It's *not* a refund, it's a compensation payment.

Comment: Ah okay, my bad. In Washington DC, if the metro gets delayed by more than 15 minutes, we automatically get the fare of the ride refunded. So that is what I thought.

Comment: This is due to UK tax law, the company is the one that has paid the ticket and is responsible for the taxes that are paid on that ticket. A refund for a ticket that is paid to an employee and kept by them is seen as a benefit in kind and would mean that the employer would have to pay extra taxes, such as National Insurance on the amount that was paid to the employee. Although this is a small amount for one employee on one occasion for a workforce over the course of a Finacial Year the tax bill could add up.